# Differences Fancy, snazzy and elegant

Tags: difference

So the word *snazzy* I don't really understand if it means the same as *fancy* or *elegant*. Are those interchangeable or not? (like when or how to use them)

Answer (score 2):

A Google search for socks is illustrative of the differences in meaning among these three adjectives.

This [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=snazzy%20socks&biw=1199&bih=1253&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwi-55T28cHOAhVGbB4KHYucDZoQ_AUIBygC) is descriptive of the word *Snazzy* as it might apply to socks.

This [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=snazzy%20socks&biw=1199&bih=1253&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwi-55T28cHOAhVGbB4KHYucDZoQ_AUIBygC#tbm=isch&q=elegant%20socks) is descriptive of the word *Elegant* as it might apply to socks.

This [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=snazzy%20socks&biw=1199&bih=1253&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwi-55T28cHOAhVGbB4KHYucDZoQ_AUIBygC#tbm=isch&q=fancy%20socks) is descriptive of the word *Fancy* as it might apply to socks.

You will note significant overlap in the images returned for the searches on *Fancy* and *Snazzy,* while *Elegant* socks are more restrained and monochromatic. In common usage, an English speaker would seldom use *Snazzy* as synonymous with *Elegant.* *Snazzy* means "loud or attention-getting, but in a positive way," as opposed to *garish* or *ostentatious.*

Answer (score 1):

Although these words are synonyms, in common usage they are very different.

Elegant is associated with the upper class, and nobility. Something elegant looks effortlessly stylish and cool.  Elegance is expensive, but not obviously so - simple diamond stud earrings are elegant, where a much more elaborate and showy piece of jewelry might seem gaudy.

In American usage, Fancy is slightly dated, and so people who use it are a little uncool.  Therefore, to say something is "Fancy" is to imply that it is impressive to the untrained eye.  "Look at you in your *fancy dress*!" can be almost insulting, if the tone is sarcastic.  I understand the British use it differently, and "fancy dress" means a costume party.

Snazzy is much more informal, and therefore more exciting.  It's no longer current slang, and evokes mid-to-early 20th century hipsters.  Someone who says "You look snazzy" is probably genuine, if a little arch.  Think bright colors and bold designs - snazzy is about breaking tradition.

To illustrate, a nice suit one might wear to church on Sunday is Fancy.  A fitted tuxedo is elegant.  A Zoot Suit is snazzy.

[...and if you're ever in doubt, you can always fall back on "cool".  Cool is timeless.]

Comment: "Fancy" is common, and far from dated, in the rural midwestern U.S. It describes anything which is even slightly beyond utilitarian, and is very slightly negative, or very slightly admiring, in sense. Heard just yesterday: _"They even have some fancy stuff at Walmart."_

Comment: @P.E.Dant You are absolutely correct, and I considered including that information, but I didn't want to prejudice anyone into thinking the rural midwest was in any way unhip.  ;)

Comment: There is nothing hip about the rural midwestern U.S., @MikeKozar , as the locals will proudly tell you!